# mysterious number 18888888888888888

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

One of our testers, managed to set a slider bound variable to 18888888888888888 which can only take values between 1-100 normally. (I can observe it in view model which is saved to a xaml file.) What's special about this number?

Here are some details. The application has a slider, it is bound to an observable property in a view model. Normally, when application saves the workspace, this viewmodel is saved along using XamlServices.Save. My tester reported some awkward behaviour, the value of the slider showing -214 upon loading this project. I asked him to send me the file and the value in the saved xaml contains my mysterious number.

I know this is the result of a bug in my code, or some other library code. I will hopefully nail it down. However, normal "garbage" values cannot be like this. When I google, I see some non-programming related pages, which shows somehow this number was generated in history of internet (so it's not my cat's doing). In short, I am trying to figure out, how this number can be created in the first place, like when you see INT_MAX + 1, if you are experienced enough you can recognize it (-2137483648 anyone?).

Comment: @KorayBalci: Can you repro?  Closed because there's really no definitive answer, thus all that remains is speculation.

Comment: @SLC and Will, I don't know if I am not clear enough, probably this is the result of a bug, an overflow most probably. I will try to repro and debug. However, you cannot tell me that this is just a random number at all, a 1 followed by 16 8s? It should be a side effect of a bug but I am curious how it can be produced. Just google the number only, there are some weird occurences, probably result of a similar bug (and their authors probably not even aware of the issue). Or, I am just trolling and posting an awkward number for fun, but this is no ordinary random number. Hope I am clear.

Comment: Tester is also a client and neither that skilled nor that funny. She has somehow the video of the process, I will have access to it next week though. the app is in early beta, so probably it's an awkward bug.

Comment: The slider is bound to a double.

Comment: Can the moderator please step up and tell me why s/he has deleted my comment? I am perfectly OK with deleting comments that were discussing why this question was closed as not constructive(and reopened and closed again). However my first comment was completely on the subject, telling 8s might correspond to nibbles, hence there are 16 of them. While we are at it, let me give you another reason to delete this one too: this question is not about a bug in .NET framework and using XAML as serialization, etc. It is just about 'double', sorry if it is too localized for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the 1 at the beginning is a place holder - an error of displaying a double to string.

We've got 16 8's.  The double type in C# has up to 16 bytes of precision.  This may indicate that the slider display is trying to show some type of garbage double value of 8888888888888888, or 0x1000100010001000100010001000100010001000100010001000100010001000.

It may be that the tester caused the value of the double to become some kind of NaN value. (maybe NaN is displayed like this)  That would definitely explain the length of the string.

Also, because of the restrictions of the slider class display showing *only* numbers, it was probably supposed to read 1x8888888888888888.  Garbage in, garbage out?

Well, that's my guess.

Comment: thanks for the effort, I will think about it, you might have nailed it. now the question is closed again though. after all these upvotes and discussions, some people just decided on behalf of us and everyone else... thank you officers for protecting people from extraordinarily narrow situations. let's all discuss how we can play a sound in iPhone.